# Upgrade Subversion to 1.7 on 8.04

Tags: apt, svn, 8.04

It comes with version 1.5 and I'd like to update it to 1.7. Is it possible? It seems that I don't have `apt-add-repository` on this system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a PPA from ["Subversion Team"](https://launchpad.net/~svn/+archive/ppa), so it should be safe. If you cannot use `add-apt-repository` you can add the corresponding repository manually in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/svn/ppa/ubuntu hardy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/svn/ppa/ubuntu hardy main
```

and importing the corresponding key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A2F4C039
```

Comment: I had to use hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 because of firewall issues.